# Different back-end colour scheme for the different sites of a multisite

Tags: multisite, users

Is it possible to have a different back-end colour scheme selected for the different sites of a multisite?

i.e. "Sunrise" for Site A and "Midnight" for Site B

If it's not possible for the user to setup could it be enforced through a plugin or the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your functions.php file the following code, this will hook into your admin header section and will place the style you chose accordingly to the matching site.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_background');

function my_admin_background() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
  );
      global $blog_id;
      $color = '';
      if ($blog_id == 1) {
         $color = 'white';
      } elseif ($blog_id == 2) {
         $color = 'red';
      } elseif ($blog_id == 3) {
         $color = 'blue';
      } else {
         $color = 'yellow';
      } 
      $custom_css = "<style> body { background: $color } </style>";
  wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
```

Comment: This plugin only seems to add CSS to the front-end of the sites. I am searching for a way to change the back-end look to make it easier to distinguish the sites at a glance.

Comment: Check my edited answer, this should do the job.

Comment: Rather than dump the CSS into the `<head>` of the backend, consider using the function [`wp_add_inline_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style). To use in in the backend, you can hook it to the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action hook instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts` as shown in the Codex page's example.

Comment: You'r right @PatJ , I think now is a better code.

Comment: Thanks! This got me what I wanted. I changed it a bit though to directly enqueue the stylesheet depending on the `$blog_id`, as that saves me the hassle of figuring out the specific selectors to overwrite with a custom style.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use the "get_user_option_admin_color" filter. This way you can choose an already created colour scheme which it seems like the question was asking for.

```
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color', 'change_admin_color');
function change_admin_color($result) {
if(get_current_blog_id() == 2) {
    return "light";
}
else {
    return "midnight";
}
```

Comment: v.helpful:   
for multiple color schemes, of course, add an "elseif" statement

Answer (score -1):

This is some sample code needed for making an individual color scheme.

```
wp_admin_css_color( 'classic', __( 'Classic' ), admin_url( "css/colors-classic.css" ), array(
    '#07273E', '#14568A', '#D54E21', '#2683AE'
) );
```

Source file: `wp-includes/general-template.php`

```
/**
 * Register color schemes.
 */
 function add_colors()
```

Example: Scroll down to find the color scheme that you duplicated, and copy all the code, paste it at the bottom of that function, and give it your custom color scheme name. In the end, the bottom two options (before the function is closed) should look something like this:

```
wp_admin_css_color(
 'seashore', __( 'Seashore', 'admin_schemes' ),
 plugins_url( "seashore/colors$suffix.css", __FILE__ ),
 array( '#F8F6F1', '#d5cdad', '#7D6B5C', '#456a7f' ),
 array( 'base' => '#533C2F', 'focus' => '#F8F6F1', 'current' => '#F8F6F1' )
 );

wp_admin_css_color(
 'matt', __( 'Matt', 'admin_schemes' ),
 plugins_url( "matt/colors$suffix.css", __FILE__ ),
 array( '#1F2C39', '#2c3e50', '#1abc9c', '#f39c12' ),
 array( 'base' => '#f1f2f3', 'focus' => '#fff', 'current' => '#fff' )
 );
```

Comment: Answers should be more than plain links. Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info in your answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you for adding the block div to make it easier to read Pieter.

Comment: Pleasure :-). Tip: If you add code in the editor, highlight the code, and click on the `{}` button above the editor, this will add your code in a code block. Alternatively, indent each line of code with 4 spaces. :-)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Do I still get minus points even though I edited the post?

Comment: Downvotes depends on other users. Bad or not so good quality answers/questions usually attract downvotes. However, downvotes can be removed with proper edits, like I have done. I only have control over my downvote. Whether or not the other downvote will be removed depends on the user who gave it. If he sees fit, he will remove the downvote. We all go down that route at some stage where an answer or question gets downvoted. You should never take that personally. Downvotes (like upvotes) are merely an indicator how useful someone found your post. Never ever let downvotes get to you :-)

Comment: Maybe I'm just really sensitive. I'll try not to post from now on unless I have something useful to say or some useful code. I don't ever want to get negative points for trying to help if possible. I would rather have a vote up system like FaceBook if possible. Their system promotes positive feedback without the bad feeling of being voted down. I guess if posts were bad they could just be moved down to the bottom of the thread without visually showing the negative points.

Sorry if this sounds bad it's my first time to this site. Respect to all the people that help others here though ^^